# Is there any lite SVG viewer for Android?

Tags: android, svg

Does android have any support for viewing SVG files or are there any 3rd party SVG viewers for the Android platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ in my application with satisfaction. All my graphic resources are stored in svg format and rendered on the fly.

Now I'm using a fork of the original project:
https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android

Simply include the .java files into your project and use them. This fork bring some improvements to the original code.

Obviously you need to code a little to build up your own SVG viewer. But it's very simple:

```
SVG svg = new SVGBuilder()
            .readFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.someSvgResource)
            .build();

Drawable drawable = svg.createDrawable();
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

So all you need it's a ImageView component on your activity.

**EDIT 2013-06-08:**

I suggest to try also this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136239/Android-ImageView-and-Drawable-with-SVG-Support

that has its own SVG parser.

Answer (score 1):

No native support AFAIK. There's this [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/svgt/index.html). Haven't actually tried it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll be able to do this with opera widgets when Opera 10.50 comes to android. Here's an [SVG viewing Opera widget which works for desktop](http://widgets.opera.com/widget/15172/).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is a lite svg viewer: 
[SVG Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.codefuture.svgviewer)